# How to generate random codes, and run an sql multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query I need to run and I have 2 problems.

first here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO  `anzie_oscommerce`.`discount_codes` (
`discount_codes_id` ,
`discount_description` ,
`products_id` ,
`categories_id` ,
`manufacturers_id` ,
`excluded_products_id` ,
`customers_id` ,
`orders_total` ,
`order_info` ,
`exclude_specials` ,
`discount_codes` ,
`discount_values` ,
`minimum_order_amount` ,
`expires_date` ,
`number_of_orders` ,
`number_of_use` ,
`number_of_products` ,
`status`
)
VALUES (
'' ,  'GALA 2012', '' , '' , '' , '' , '' ,  '2',  '1',  '0',  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8),  250,  '0.0000',  '2013-22-06',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1'
);
```

The first problem is I need to generate the random code which I am trying to do with the uniqid function I took from php but I know that is not possible. Is there a way to do something similar in sql?

The second problem is I need to run this 250 times to generate 250 different discount codes. Is there a quick way to run an sql multiple times?

Comment: Are you looking for a random id or just unique ones? That is, are you concerned about someone being able to guess a code from another one?

Comment: I think random as well as unique. since as you say the codes should not be able to be easily guessed. I think the php code that I included in the sql statement does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem: it depends on the database you're using.  Mysql has a rand() function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

For the second: 250 is not many for a database - just putting it in a php for loop would most likely be fine.

Comment: I guess I can do that yea. Just curious no way to do it directly from phpmyadmin?

Comment: I ended up doing it this way. Very simple and I was able to generate the codes the same way as before since it was a php method. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I think the only way to do this repetitively would be to put your insert statement in a stored procedure and wrap it in a REPEAT (or other type of) loop.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer sonofagun answer. Another trick is to select from a dummy table 250 times.

```
INSERT INTO  `anzie_oscommerce`.`discount_codes` (
`discount_codes_id` ,
`discount_description` ,
`products_id` ,
`categories_id` ,
`manufacturers_id` ,
`excluded_products_id` ,
`customers_id` ,
`orders_total` ,
`order_info` ,
`exclude_specials` ,
`discount_codes` ,
`discount_values` ,
`minimum_order_amount` ,
`expires_date` ,
`number_of_orders` ,
`number_of_use` ,
`number_of_products` ,
`status`
)
(select '' ,  'GALA 2012', '' , '' , '' , '' , '' ,  '2',  '1',  '0',  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8),  250,  '0.0000',  '2013-22-06',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1' union all
select '' ,  'GALA 2012', '' , '' , '' , '' , '' ,  '2',  '1',  '0',  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8),  250,  '0.0000',  '2013-22-06',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1' union all
select '' ,  'GALA 2012', '' , '' , '' , '' , '' ,  '2',  '1',  '0',  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8),  250,  '0.0000',  '2013-22-06',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1' union all
select '' ,  'GALA 2012', '' , '' , '' , '' , '' ,  '2',  '1',  '0',  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8),  250,  '0.0000',  '2013-22-06',  '0',  '1',  '0',  '1' union all
...however many times
);
```